# Is there a way to build a yocto image in Yocto(1.8) with wandboard-solo as the target machine?

Tags: yocto

I'm trying to build a yocto Image for wandboard-solo using yocto 1.8. While the earlier versions of yocto had wandboard as one of the options in target architecture, yocto 1.8 doesn't seem to have it by default.

"Please set a valid MACHINE in your local.conf or environment"

I'm getting this error when I set the MACHINE variable in the local.conf file to wandboard-solo

https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-94914

This is a tutorial for an earlier version where wandboard-solo was an option. However, the list of currently supported machines is -

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-MACHINE

Is there a way to make Yocto 1.8 work for wandboard?

Comment: Which layers have you added?

Comment: Hi Anders, I have meta, meta-selftest, meta-skeleton, meta-yocto, and meta-yocto-bsp in my poky folder. Does that help?

Comment: Ok, that's one of your issues then. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll need to add a BSP-layer with support for the wandboard-family. Yocto (or rather Poky), does only have support for one board for each architecture. This is only for HW verification of the build system. For the arm architecture, the HW reference platform is currently BeagleBone Black.

The wandboard family of boards are supported by the meta-fsl-arm-extra layer, https://github.com/Freescale/meta-fsl-arm-extra.

If you're using the `fido`release, or earlier, the meta-fsl-arm-extra layer will provide you with a `wandboard-solo` machine. If, on the other hand, you're building from master (i.e. what will become the next release after `fido`), the different wandboard-machines has been unified into one, `wandboard`. See the commit https://github.com/Freescale/meta-fsl-arm-extra/commit/ba9a5943ead5dbf87e973cd6e5803405faba7a6c for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note: if you want to know if a specific board is supported and by which layers, the OpenEmbedded layer index can come handy. You can select the release you are using (in your case, fido), and then search for your board in the machines tab:

http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/fido/machines/?q=wandboard